# How to use Join in criteria API in JPA

Tags: jpa, join, criteria-api

I am new to criteria API of JPA.

If there is a `@OneToMany` relationship between an Employee and a PhoneNumber entities

```
Join <Employee,PhoneNumber >  join=employee.join(Employee_.phoneNumber);
```

What information does the "join" object contain and how to use the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Behind the scenes you can think at it as a `Path<PhoneNumber>`, i.e. an object from which you can extract the properties of a `PhoneNumber` entity like follows:

```
Expression<MyPropertyType> myProperty = join.get("myProperty");
```

or, if you use MetaModel like you did in the question,

```
Expression<MyPropertyType> myProperty = join.get(PhoneNumber_.myProperty);
```

In other words, the join method transforms a `From<Employee>` or `Path<Employee>` object into a `Path<PhoneNumber>`.

**Links**:

- [Join (Java EE 6) - Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Join.html)
- [Dynamic, typesafe queries in JPA 2.0](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-typesafejpa/)